# Customizing Tags page in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way to modify the layout of the /Tags and /Tags/[tag] pages via placement.info and/or a custom view?

For the majority of work i've done on my theme i'm able to move my title from the Content zone into the Header zone via the following:

```
<Place Parts_Title="/Header:1"/>
```

However, when i use the shape tracing tool to see what the title of the tags page is, i get the following:

```
Zone[Content]
    List
       Content
           Parts_Title_Summary
           Parts_Common_Body_Summary
           DateTime
           Parts_Tags_ShowTags
       Content
           Parts_Title_Summary
           Parts_Common_Body_Summary
           DateTime
           Parts_Tags_ShowTags
       Content
           Parts_Title_Summary
           Parts_Common_Body_Summary
           DateTime
           Parts_Tags_ShowTags
```

I cant find any views to override, nor can i find any particular parts that i can move.

I'm relatively new to orchard, so perhaps i'm approaching this the wrong way. I'm open to changing it but i'm a little lost as to how i can move the title of the tag i've viewing into a top level zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take over the full rendering, you can override the controller's views ([see documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/#alternates-for-mvc-views)). If you take a look at the Orchard.Tags module, you can see that it uses controller views. You can override those in your theme:

- MyTheme/Views/Orchard.Tags/Home/Index.cshtml
- MyTheme/Views/Orchard.Tags/Home/Search.cshtml

If you just want to move around some parts you should use the Placement.info though.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you :D